# Python 2: How do I search for a string in a text file before returning the entire line from the text file that contains this string?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Use case:
The user enters an ID code. 
A stored file contains information about people, one line per person, including their ID codes.
I need to find this user's line in the file and append that to another text file.

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
for line in file:
    if id_code in line:
        yield line
```

Now  what? How do I go from yielding the line to getting it in another file? Also, if the id code isn't in the file at all, can I ask them to try again?

Comment: this is not code writing resource, please provide your codes first

Comment: You're welcome.  You're great, too.  Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes, Brian. It is written just above where you wrote your thing

Comment: Can you give us an example line from the file?

Comment: Scripted the introduction as a proper use case; easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the actual txt file, it's hard to say if this will work perfectly, but it's the right general idea.

```
with open("file.txt", "r") as f, open("otherfile.txt", "a") as g:
    for line in file.readlines():
        lineparts = line.split()
            if id_code in lineparts:
                g.write(line)
```